# How to synchronize animations across usercontrols in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, synchronization

I am creating several usercontrols in a wrap panel. I have a view model bound to the usercontrol and I have an animation triggered to a property in the view model. Very simple toggle color from red to transparent to simulate flashing.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="alertAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" >
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                  Storyboard.TargetName="TileBorder"
                                  BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                  AutoReverse="True"
                                  >
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Red"/>
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.500" Value="Transparent" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

</Storyboard>
```

This works just fine. However, since I load multiple usercontrols asynchronously the blinking animations are not synchronized so they all blink at different times. There is now a requirement that anything blinking on the screen needs to all blink at the same rate/time. Is there a way to sync these animations? I cannot seem to find an example anywhere that fits what I am trying to accomplish. Is there a way to use the ParallelTimeline, add all the animations to it and start/stop them from a single controller? Any examples how to accomplish this out there?

EDIT 4/20
Would it be better to have the animation defined in a style.xaml file and have a "global" storyboard that each controls adds its "blink" animation to and have the main UI start the storyboard?

Comment: Why do you need to load the controls asynch?

Comment: Really for looks. I found if I loaded them synchronously then the application appeared to hang until all controls are loaded. Also, once all initial user controls get loaded another one could appear at anytime as a device it represents comes online. I figured I needed to solve that case as well.

Comment: Seems like a simple animation but I would try discrete over key frame.

Comment: I am open to change the animation to anything that creates a blinking effect. I'll take a look at the discrete option. Any ideas on how to link all the blink animations to a single timeline?

Comment: Actually which animation are you specifically talking about? I do not want a fade effect, just instant red then transparent repeating forever.

Comment: See my answer.  A duration of 0 gets an immediate change.  Not sure how to get that to cycle.  To synch up up you might need to bind them all to a color property and then use a background type process to change the color.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a good way to control multiple animations across multiple usercontrols so I ended up not using animation in the usercontrol but instead use an animation to simply change a dependencyproperty in a static object and have all usercontrols that need to blink in some fashion bind to that property. There are various ways to produce the desired results I wanted but ultimately I now had a way for all my controls to know when blink was on and then off so that everything is synchronized.

I got the idea and sample code from the following site:
[How to synchronize animations across usercontrols in wpf](http://dotnetlearning.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/synchronizing-animations-across-different-threads/)

I made a few modifications to it but overall it did exactly what I needed it to do.

Comment: This is what I'm going at the moment. I was hoping just to use animations. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this would need to be modified but a try a duration of 0 on a color transition may give you a blink with less overhead.  And it may not.   Just something to try.

```
    <Rectangle Name="MyRectangle" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
            From="100" To="200" Duration="0:0:1" />

                        <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="Blue" To="Red" BeginTime="0:0:1"  Duration="0:0:0"  />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```

Comment: If you're trying to get "true blinking" with storyboards then animation with keyframes is the way to go. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-a-double-by-using-key-frames